# Read and Write rules In a proper way Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

How can I test if a username exists in the proper way? This code is not working. Do I have to update my rules in some sort of way? Im not too familiar with firebase rules.

**Rules:**

```
{
    "rules": {
         "Users":{
             ".read": "true",
             ".write": "true"
          }
     }
}
```

**Current JSON Tree Setup:**

```
+Users
    +iq5oM0XlgAa9K78EuEFdZ0ZVTsm1
    Email: "test@gmail.com"
    Name: "jj"
    Password: "***"
    Username: "jjj"
```

**CODE:**

```
let username : String = self.usernameField.text!

        //Checking username existence
        FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Users/Username").child(username).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(usernameSnap) in

            if usernameSnap.exists(){
                //This username already exists
                print("The user name already exists")
            }else{

                //Yippee!.. This can be my username
                print("user good to go")
                print(username)
            }

        })
```

Comment: Im really stuck

Comment: has to be something like Users/UID/Username. Ive been trying for so long i just dont know

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a separate node in your database called `usernames`. Here you save the username as the key, and the userID as the value. Now you can check the usernames node to see if a username already exists.